# swift how to get same function name

Tags: swift, function, selector, equals

show me code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("1 \(#function))")
    let selector = #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLoad)
    print("2 \(NSStringFromSelector(selector))")
}
```

and log:

```
1 viewDidLoad()
2 viewDidLoad
```

but i expectant twice log is same,
What method can achieve？ 
Thanks!

Comment: What you are actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: twice log is same

Comment: See you are printing function and second time string from function which means name of function(viewDidLoad). It could not be same. And what you actually trying to do with these prints? As your question is very unclear.

Comment: I have dict(NSMutableDictionary), and I through NSStringFromSelector(selector) as key,  something as value.

when call function, for expamle viewDidLoad , i want use #function to find dict' value. but NSStringFromSelector(selector) is not equal to #function , so i cann't find the value. sorry expression is not good.

Comment: No problem , let assume your dictionary 
{
   viewDidLoad : "Its Value",
   viewDidAppear:"Its Value",
  viewWillAppear:"Its value"
}


}